# How to findout the sender of a transaction

Tags: bitcoind

How do I find out which addresses are the inputs of a given transaction, given its transaction ID?
I know there is a way, as satoshidice.com uses this.
I would like to do this with own software and not rely on some third party provider, which could easily kill their service.

EDIT:

Basically I'm creating a PHP project, where I need to find out when a new transaction arrives and which address sent it. So I need a way to get a notification or start a PHP script (called with needed variables [txid, sender address, receiving address, value]) when a new transaction arrives.

Comment: I edited your question to tidy up the grammar and spelling, but also fixed the assumption that there is a single "sender" address.  It's quite possible that the transaction has multiple inputs and multiple outputs, so there's no single "sender".  SatoshiDICE doesn't care; it just sends the winnings to one of the sending addresses.

Answer (score 10):

I just answered [a similar question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/whats-the-best-way-for-a-website-to-detect-payments-from-green-addresses/5981#5981). The relevant parts are:

It is now possible to determine the list of addresses that sent a transaction using the raw transaction [JSON-RPC API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_Calls_list) calls that were released with bitcoind and bitcoin-qt version 0.7. The pseudo-code to accomplish this is:

```
txid = <relevant transaction id>
addresses = []
raw_tx = decoderawtransaction(getrawtransaction(txid))
for(input in raw_tx['vin']) {
  input_raw_tx = decoderawtransaction(getrawtransaction(input['txid']))
  addresses.push(input_raw_tx['vout'][input['vout']]['scriptPubKey']['addresses'][0])
}
```

Comment: Trying to find out the same thing, your  "decoderawtransaction(getrawtransaction(input['txid']))" instruction failed at first. However, the problem fixed itself and your example worked after I waited for raw_tx['confirmation'] and raw_tx['blockhash'] to be defined.

Comment: this basically scans through the blockchain for the output transaction corresponding to the hash value in the later input-transaction. is there not a way of getting the answer using the input scriptsig though?

Comment: Asked a [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66900/1891) related to your pseudocode. Would appreciate if you can take a look.

Comment: Note that if your wallet did not sent the previous transaction, you will need to [enable `txindex=1`](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35707/what-are-pros-and-cons-of-txindex-option) in bitcoin.conf to track non-wallet transactions. Otherwise, the call to `getrawtransaction` will fail

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin.org client doesn't provide this.

I believe your options are:

- Armory
- libbitcoin
- ABE blockchain explorer
- BitcoinJ http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj

Comment: i thought about using ABE but i were told uses about 1,4GB of ram, which is just to much for my "small" vps with 2GB of ram in total. Are the other more "lightweight" ?