# How can I find the sender's address from the transaction hash?

Tags: payment, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to findout the sender of a transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/how-to-findout-the-sender-of-a-transaction)

I am trying to use blockchain.info API to receive a payment and store the sender's address. However, the API only indicates the transaction hash, not the sender's address. Perhaps this is simply ignorance about the BTC Protocol, but **how can I find the sender's address from any given transaction hash?**

The two API's I am using:

- https://blockchain.info/api/api_receive
- https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can for example check the Block Explorer's info about a given transaction. For example, given transaction [1c480aad976c61b51ae47401a554b09f65efe6f95f644041f838d9129e09167c](http://blockexplorer.com/tx/1c480aad976c61b51ae47401a554b09f65efe6f95f644041f838d9129e09167c), you can see that the only input was associated with address 1HnjAo2nbHGFDto86smcFiF3uUwfvNJ4cS.

However, generally you should avoid using transaction inputs for basically any purpose - they do not uniquely identify a user, sending Bitcoins back to the user might be problematic with just this information and so forth.

Comment: OK... Thanks for answering. Where Can I found that here? Is it the "hash" of "prevout"?
https://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api

Comment: @flaab You'd have to parse the website, not the raw Tx, as a Bitcoin transaction does not encode the previous transaction. If you want to use raw Tx, you would need to take the `prev_out` `hash` and `n`, go to the transaction of that hash and check the `out` with an index `n`.