# How to access any transaction detail in Bitcoin version 0.8 and above?

Tags: transactions, client, bitcoin-core, json-rpc, raw-data

Since the [Standard Client version 0.8](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bitcoin/files/Bitcoin/bitcoin-0.8.0/) removed the full index of all historical transactions, some Bitcoin applications that relied on that functionality have stopped working. For example, one is no longer able to [find out the sender of a given transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5982/323) by pure RPC calls. How can one access that transaction detail in the newer versions of the Bitcoin client?

Comment: You cannot find the sender of a transaction in any case. You can find the addresses the input coins were previously sent to, but that is not necessarily the sender of the transaction, and not useful in general.

Answer (score 5):

Two new command-line or bitcoin.conf file commands have been added in the 0.8 release that allow for historical transactions to be accessible by recreating the old index:

> txindex : maintains an extra index of old, spent transaction ids so they will be found
>   by the getrawtransaction JSON-RPC method.
>
> reindex : rebuild block and transaction indices from the downloaded block data.

[...]

> you must run once
>   with -txindex=1 -reindex=1 to rebuild block-chain indices

Comment: How do I make sure the Bitcoin client maintains this transaction index always even when it frequently synchronises and download new blocks?

Comment: @Myth17 I think it keeps the index after you set the index flag.

Comment: I am facing issues with raw transactions even after with flags set: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/17451/getrawtransaction-in-bitcoin-qt-0-8-5