# Installed latest Bitcoin-Qt, fully synced, but 'getreceivedbyaddress' etc doesn't work?

Tags: bitcoind

I downloaded and installed Bitcoin-Qt 0.8.6, fully synced the block chain ([according to the software itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75sq3.png)) and now trying some basic commands through the console.

For some reason, `getreceivedbyaddress <address>` always returns zero, even for addresses that I know contain some bitcoins.

For example: `getreceivedbyaddress 1Dorian4RoXcnBv9hnQ4Y2C1an6NJ4UrjX` gives 0.00000000 ([mini-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMoJV.png)), yet we can all verify that this address actually *did* receive bitcoins (see comment).

Restarted the software several times, restarted my PC, and also tried doing this from the command line using bitcoind instead of the Bitcoin-Qt user interface, still the same result.

Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding Bitcoin-Qt?

Comment: Can't post more than 2 links, but here's to show that this address indeed has a positive BTC balance: https://blockchain.info/address/1Dorian4RoXcnBv9hnQ4Y2C1an6NJ4UrjX

Comment: The answer is here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/19739/1878

Comment: try bitcoind listaddressgroupings see if that shows which address the BTC are in.

Answer (score 2):

`getreceivedbyaddress` only works for *your* addresses, i.e. those for which the private key is in your wallet.  Those are the only addresses for which `bitcoin-qt` keeps indexed transaction data.  Getting balance and transaction information for arbitrary addresses is unfortunately not supported by `bitcoin-qt`; sites like blockchain.info write custom software that manually parses the block chain.

See also [this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/10099/5757).

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Is there a way to (perhaps temporarily) add such addresses to my wallet? Because I don't have the private key, I can only do so in a read-only way (like a 'watch only' wallet or address) but is this supported at all by Bitoin-Qt / bitcoind?

Comment: Now that I think of it, perhaps this could be faked by somehow importing this address in an encrypted wallet, with a dummy private key? Bitcoin-Qt won't ask for my password (and hence, not use this private key at all) until I actually try to spend something...?

Comment: @Monty: I believe that bitcoin-qt does not have support for watch only wallets, though other clients might. Your encrypted wallet suggestion might work, I suppose, but it sounds like a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that getreceivedbyaddress only reports on addresses that *are in your wallet*.  It doesn't allow you to look up arbitrary addresses, like the 1Dorian one.