# "offline" blockchain querying library

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, blockchain.info

Is there a library which provides all the same address/transaction querying information as blockchain.info, depending only on having a bitcoind synchronised database?

There are a number of queries which bitcoind cannot answer. For example, bitcoind only indexes transactions which are unspent.

I realize blockchain.info has a public API, but it isn't an option for us to use this. I doubt they'd want us to spider the entire blockchain over their API anyway.

Comment: Technically, it doesn't any transactions at all. It just maintains a set of unspent transaction outputs. `-txindex` will make it maintain a full transaction index, but that is still only by txids, and not by address/script.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [**Abe**](https://github.com/bitcoin-abe/bitcoin-abe):

**Abe**: a free block chain browser for Bitcoin-based currencies.

Abe reads the Bitcoin block file, transforms and loads the data into a database, and presents a web interface similar to [**Bitcoin Block Explorer**](http://blockexplorer.com/) or [**Blockchain.io**](https://blockchain.io).

Not to mention it was written in Python.

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, you can force bitcoind to index spent transactions. More information [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11875/how-to-access-any-transaction-detail-in-bitcoin-version-0-8-and-above).

Comment: Why the downvotes?