# Parsing bitcoin blockchain, get input (vin)

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, python

I downloaded the bitcoin blockchain. I have a full node and I would like to do some parsing. I use RPC to send commands to bitcoin core from my Python program. When I get a block it works fine but the input is missing. I am forced to look for the associated transaction to "discover" the address and the value. For the output no problem, it's a [known problem](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/89207/how-to-get-input-address-and-amount-from-vin-using-bitcoin-core-rpc); the problem is that making an extra request for each input slows down my program a lot, for the moment I haven't found a solution so I'm relying on you a bit.

I tried to find a solution on the UTXO side with the gettxout command but I have to think again, not sure it does what I want.

My goal is to get a result like the one of [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/rawblock/5). Addresses don't interest me, the HEX script is enough, the input address, the output address, and the associated value.