# get any transaction in p2p manner using bitcoinj

Tags: bitcoinj

I'm pretty sure bitcoinj is capable of downloading any Bitcoin transaction from P2P nodes by broadcasting `GetDataMessage` because that's what it  does in the `peer.downloadDependenciesInternal` method.

I'm trying to find/implement a very simple method which would download a transaction with its inputs and outputs and the block in which it's included (if any) but, because of Guava asynchronous futures, I cannot figure it out.

Very simply, I would like to replace 3rd-party services like [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/tx/22164ca0760980161a8e1d8e2f962a782ce0134d535255cf8bbd49c5724008db?format=json) with something decentralized.

Answer (score 1):

GetData can fetch only **unconfirmed** transactions, and that's what `Peer.downloadDependenciesInternal` is doing.

You might want to contact the developer of the now defunct biteasy.com block explorer, he was using (and extending on) bitcoinj.

Answer (score 0):

So far, what I found out is that bitcoinj can only fetch unconfirmed 
transactions using:

```
GetDataMessage message = new GetDataMessage();
message.addTransaction(hash);
peer.sendMessage(message);
```

Message should then be received by some listener, for example:

```
peer.addPreMessageReceivedEventListener(...);
```

But confirmed transactions will not be received by this nor any similar method. If I'm wrong here I would be very happy. Simply there's no such functionality without running full node (bitcoind) with hash index.

Comment: Given that a Bitcoin Core full node cannot locate individual transactions by txid (unless txindex is enabled) for local usage, how would those same nodes be able to provide it to you over the network? If you want to find confirmed transactions, you need to synchronize the blocks (potentially with BIP37 filtering, but that has severe privacy implications).

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to replace a 3rd-party service like [blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info), then you have to run a full `bitcoind` node with `-txindex=1` and write your service to interface with it (see [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35707/what-are-pros-and-cons-of-txindex-option))

As far as I can tell, the only way to get `bitcoinj` to only download **your own** confirmed TXs (by ID) is by setting up **your** wallet with it and using the Bloom filter feature to download Merkle proofs w.r.t. to the block headers. However, this will not be helpful for your application, where you want to download **any** transaction. You will have to run a full node!