# How to get both confirmed and unconfirmed transaction details of foreign(non-wallet) addresses from bitcoin-node server?

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, unconfirmed-transactions, confirmations

How to get both confirmed and unconfirmed transaction details of foreign(non-wallet) addresses from bitcoin-node server?
Actually i have generated the addresses using third party library and sent some btc on it. Now i want to know confirmed and unconfirmed transaction details using my own local bitcoin-core node server. Can Somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which bitcoin client are you running?

Comment: bitcoin-core 0.17

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can use this command `getrawtransaction` to get a transaction that is in your node's mempool i.e. an unconfirmed transaction.

However, if you are looking for a transaction that has been confirmed, you'll need to know the blockhash of the block in which that transaction resides.

Example:

```
> bitcoin-cli getrawtransaction "mytxid" false "myblockhash"
```

Or if you have enabled `-txindex` option on your client then you can use `getrawtransaction` and you don't need to supply the blockhash. Check out [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/35707/what-are-pros-and-cons-of-txindex-option) for details on this option.

Refer to [this site](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-cli/getrawtransaction) for a more detailed explanation of the `getrawtransaction` command.

Comment: Actually i want to know the transaction that is send by others into my address and that transaction is not yet confirmed(unconfirmed).Here addresses are created outside the node. Then how we can check status of unconfirmed transactions?
Note: We don't have transaction id for unconfirmed receive transaction. We only have address.

Comment: By unconfirmed do you mean "pending" transactions or transactions in the mempool?

Comment: Yes, pending transaction of addresses which doesn't belong to my local bitcoin-core node .

Comment: The only way you can see that pending transaction is if it gets broadcasted and your local node receives it into it's mempool (AFAIK). Are you not able to see the pending transaction in your nodes mempool?

Comment: you mean to say we can get pending transaction of address into our local node  mempool (private keys & address belongs to other node)?

Comment: No, I'm saying you'll have to wait for your node to see the broadcasted transaction. Once a transaction is broadcasted it gets propagated throughout the network. You have to wait for your node to see that transaction.

Comment: Actually addresses are generated outside the node and now i want to create transaction using these addresses. i used createrawtransaction then while calculating fee i am getting error in fundrawtransaction

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scantxoutset` command which was introduced in Bitcoin Core 0.17. It scans the UTXO set for any UTXOs for the address (or output script) provided. It is faster than the rescan when you import a private key.

Type `help scantxoutset` to see the help. 
https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#scantxoutset

Comment: Thanks m1xolyd1an, scantxoutset gives details of confirmed transactions. I am looking for unconfirmed transactions also.